# Why do cars have so many biological characteristics in the post-human era?

Tags: cars

Disney's *Cars* is set is a post-human world in which sentient machines rule.

Many obvious questions are left unanswered. What happened to the humans? Why do cars retain so many human cultural imprints (eg, Queen of England, Route 66, Tokyo billboards)? How do they manipulate their built world when most of them lack appendages?

But the most confusing part for me is is their apparent mechanical-biological nature. Cars drink fuel, have teeth and tongues, speak and cough. Wireless communication would be much more efficent for sentient machines.

Why do cars have so many biological characteristics in the post-human era?

Comment: Are you sure it's set in a "post-human" world? Or is it simply a world where humans never existed?

Comment: You seem to be asking several questions here. It would help your question's prospects if you narrowed it down to one question or split it into several questions.

Comment: The only answer I can come up with is out-of-universe, which is... *because that the whole point of the movie*. While many SF/F films are are geared toward children and Disney is on-topic here, I am not sure if Cars as a select movie is. There are no SFF elements beyond "sentient cars".

Comment: [Personification](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personification) is an excellent way to create an emotional connection to the non-human characters.

Comment: The question makes an assumption without evidence. Why assume that it's a post-human world, instead of a world that never had humans?

Answer (score 5):

### "Cars" movie is not Post-human

Disney's movie is a typical anthropomorphic story - one where non human creatures (in this case cars and other vehicles) behave like humans. Its an old trope, ancient Greek Aesop was most famous for such kind of stories.
You can see that in "Cars" (ad "Planes") universe there are no humans or animals - cows are tractors, birds are little planes etc. It is not because such creatures gone extinct - they never existed in first place. Don't ask how is it possible, its not SF, its a kids story, akin to i.e. "The Wind in the Willows" but where author decided to have sentient vehicles instead of animals.

To improve the anthropomorphic effect cars representing certain our-world people are cars that have similar characters - i.e. Finn McMissle is a James Bond like agent, so of course he has to be a most famous Bond car - Aston, Arnold Schwarzenegger in first part is a big and tough guy, so is replaced by Hummer and Queen of England looks like (arguably) most royal car of all - the Rolls Royce.

Answer (score -2):

Why do we have fingernails? They used to be claws. Why do we mostly have the same diameter when making a circle with thumb and other fingers? Because that was the average branch diameter of the trees we lived in. Evolutionary holdovers are everywhere if you look for them. They don't have to make sense, they simply are.

Comment: I fail to see why this has earned down votes. I'm proposing a (perhaps the only) vaguely scientifically reasonable explanation. Perhaps if I suggested instead that they were created that way 5,000 years ago?

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but I suspect it might be because there is *no* scientifically reasonable explanation. I doubt cars could evolve, let alone cars with humanoid attributes. Suggesting that they were created by the Car God would probably make *more* sense.

Comment: Our Ford and Savior?